How to copy commits from a branch to another
so I want to copy a branch but have the copied branch to be based on main.
        main
         |
A---B---C   (main)
     \
      D---E   (branch A)

        main
         |
A---B---C   (main)
     \
      D---E   (branch A)
           \
            D'---E'   (branch B, copy of branch A)

        main
         |
A---B---C           (main)
     \     \
      \     D'---E'   (branch B, copy of branch A, rebased onto main)
       \
        D---E   (branch A)

Is there an easy way of doing this? I'm still very new to git besides the normal pull and push commands.
I've tried to use git checkout with the copy flag, and then rebasing using the --onto flag, but when I did this, all the commits from branch A were not part from branch B.

Do not describe what you did. Show the commands and their output.

You cannot have D' and E' on top of D and E, because the changes are already there. You cannot have the same changes twice in the same branch. What is your exact goal?

If you want to copy D and E onto C, then rebase or cherry-pick are your friends

Your second example is not possible (you cannot copy a commit after itself – the changes are already included in the branch).
But to get from your first graph to your third graph is simple: either use git rebase or git cherry-pick:
git checkout -b B A # create new branch B from A
git rebase main     # rebase commits of current branch (B) to main

git checkout -b B main # create new branch B from A
git cherry-pick main..A    # copy commits from A to your current branch (B)

Both rebasing and cherry-picking create new commits (with new hashes).
